# Mean of Means - How to aggregate means of different sample sizes

Tags: r, math, mean

How do I think about taking the average of several different averages?

Here is some data:

```
library(dplyr)
month <- c("January", "January","January", "February", "March", "April", "April", "May", "June", "July")
year <- c(2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014, 2014)
v1 <- c(0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1)
df <- data.frame(month, year, v1)
```

As you can see, I have different sample sizes for different months. January's sample size is 3, April's sample size is 2, etc.

I can take the average of each of them, gaining a mean for every month:

```
 df %>% group_by(year, month) %>% summarize_all(mean)
```

However, how do I get a *correct* mean for the year 2014, given that I have the mean of several months, where each monthly mean had varying sample sizes?

Comment: Is this a statistics question? You just `group_by(year)` assuming each row is a sample as it appears in your data. Alternatively, you can use `weighted.mean()`

Comment: Yes, I suppose it is a statistics question. I am not certain if it requires any sort of weighting given that the monthly averages were created with different sample sizes.

Comment: You're more likely to get help on statistics questions by posting on cross validated: https://stats.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both methods of averaging give you the same value:

Here's simply taking the yearly average:

```
df %>% group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(year_avg = mean(v1))
```

Compare with taking the average of monthly averages where each month has a different sample:

```
df %>% group_by(year, month) %>% 
  summarise(month_avg = mean(v1), samples = n()) %>%
  summarise(year_avg = weighted.mean(month_avg, samples))
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't have the rep to comment.  Your question is unclear, what is it you want to calculate?  Do you want the mean *monthly* average?

Given the lack of data in some months I wonder whether it's appropriate to calculate a mean in each month.  If you just want the straightforward mean for 2014 then there is no need to group into months, you can just calculate the sample mean.

Comment: I have a varying amount of daily binary observations that I am aggregating into monthly data by taking the mean. However, I am also interested in not just looking at the mean for each month, I am also curious as to the mean for the year. 

I see your point now that I can just take the mean from the un-aggregated data instead of trying to take the mean of several means that were calculated for the monthly level.